# Rendering QML over another window using QWidget

Tags: qt, qml

I am currently using QWidget to embed a window from another library (Panda3D). I've been trying to see if it was possible to add a QML-based interface to Panda3D by rendering a QQuickView over the QWidget containing Panda3D's window.

When I don't initialize Panda3D, I can see my QQuickView being properly rendered over the widget: but when I do reparent Panda3D's window to the widget, then the window is rendered over the QQuickView.

I'd like to know if what I'm trying to do is possible, and if yes, how would I do such a thing ?

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: QT5.3 added QQuickWidget for that I think http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qquickwidget.html